# How do I combine two Schemas in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a MongoDB with the following two schmemas:

```
Survey:
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e4ed11c73c4c900ef824b8a"
    },
    "isRunning": false,
    "title": "TestSurvey",
    "dateOfCreation": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1582223644144"
        }
    },
    "dateOfExpiration": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1592438400000"
        }
    },
    "isPublic": true,
    "user": {
        "$oid": "5e1f3c9868141f0055208da9"
    },
    "maxParticipants": {
        "$numberInt": "50"
    },
    "questions": [],
    "__v": {
        "$numberInt": "0"
    }
}
```

```
User:
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e1f3c9868141f0055208da9"
    },
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName": "Mueller",
    "userName": "bob",
    "email": "bob@bob.com",
    "salt": "4604426e4ac451654f28025ffe9d09e0",
    "hash": "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",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1579105433056"
        }
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1582223618030"
        }
    },
    "__v": {
        "$numberInt": "0"
    }
}
```

My goal is to make a list where I can see all the surveys that are public (isPublic: true), the userName of the user who created the survey and the expiration date of the Survey. In order for that to work I need to reference the user by using the userId in the survey schema.

In my project I have the following controller:

```
const {Survey} = require('../../models');
const {User} = require('../../models');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

class HomeController {

  async homeView(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const survey = await Survey.findOne();
      const user = await User.findOne();

      const userSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
        _id: Schema.ObjectId,
      })

      const surveySchema = new Schema({
        title: String,
        expirationDate: Date,
        creator: [userSchema]
      })

      const surveys = mongoose.model('surveys', surveySchema);

      res.render('home/homeView', {
        title: 'All surveys',
        surveys,
    });
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }

  }
}

module.exports = new HomeController();
```

As you can see I have the separate models for the user and the survey but I figure out how to combine them yet. I have tried using the Mongoose populate help page but it didn't really work out.

I hope someone can help me, as I am still new to this topic.

Answer (score 2):

This is made possible using `subdocuments`. Subdocuments allow you to declare separate models/ schemas and then link them/call them inside other schemas.

Here's a little text from the documentation: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

> Subdocuments are documents embedded in other documents. In Mongoose,
>   this means you can nest schemas in other schemas. Mongoose has two
>   distinct notions of subdocuments: arrays of subdocuments and single
>   nested subdocuments.

```
var childSchema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });

var parentSchema = new Schema({
  // Array of subdocuments
  children: [childSchema],
  // Single nested subdocuments. Caveat: single nested subdocs only work
  // in mongoose >= 4.2.0
  child: childSchema
});
```

Comment: Do I need to do this inside my controller or the file where I declare my Schemas for the user and the survey?

Comment: you can declare the child schema in one file, then export is as usual. Import the schema using the `require` command and then use the schema name as the `type` attribute.